Passing an AC voltage to a set of copper pipes (Paul trap)
I and a few other students at my university are constructing a linear ion trap as a summer project. It'll be used for outreach and science demonstrations, so the charged particles we'll be trapping will be relatively large.
Papers written on the subject suggest an AC voltage of ~1500V, which we could generate using some of the equipment supplied to us by the university. The only thing that isn't clear at this stage is how we should go about supplying the AC voltage to the device.
Our trap will consist of two endcaps holding in place four copper pipes, which will serve as the source of the trapping potential. I'll include a photo of a similar setup for clarity.
Any ideas as to how we could effectively wire this up?
edit: fixed article link


Connect everything up with wires. What frequency AC?

And, obviously, make sure it's not possible to accidentally touch any of the energized pipes.

Alas your link does not work. What is a Paul trap?

Paul traps or Radiofrequency traps.

IDK how much it matters for 1500V and low current,* but generally you want a good mechanical connection between conductors. My first thought, drill a hole in the copper, put a nut behind the hole, and a machine screw through the hole, and a terminal on the end of the wire that will be tightly held in place by the screw.
I would also probably sand the copper pipe to get rid of any patina before making the connection, and then after it's all tight, I'd put a dab of electrical grease on it and I'd wrap it tightly with black vinyl electrical tape to prevent future oxidation.

* I'm just guessing that it's going to be the electric field that matters in your apparatus, and it will draw nearly no current from the 1500V supply.

Thanks for this answer--figuring out how to properly affix the wire to the pipes was probably half the battle. As for the second part, I was thinking of switching out the copper for stainless steel to avoid patch potentials or general oxidation, though I'm not sure if that has any affect on the rest of what you'd mentioned.
